# R - gsub a specific character of a specific position

Tags: regex, r, position, gsub

I would like to delete the last character of a variable. 
I was wondering if it is possible to select the position with `gsub` and delete the character at this particular position.

In this example, I want to delete the last digit in the end, after the `E`, for my 4 variables.

```
variables = c('B10243E1', 'B10243E2', 'B10243E3', 'B10243E4')
gsub(pattern = '[[:xdigit:]]{8}.', replacement = '', x = variables)
```

I thought we could use the command

```
{}
```

in order to select a specific position.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it by capturing all the characters but the last:

```
variables = c('B10243E1', 'B10243E2', 'B10243E3', 'B10243E4')
gsub('^(.*).$', '\\1', variables)
```

Explanation:

- `^` - Start of the string
- `(.*)` - All characters but a newline up to
- `.$` - The last character (captured with `.`) before the end of string (`$`).

Thus, this regex is good to use if you plan to remove the *final* character, and the string does not contain newline.

See [demo](http://goo.gl/VXmbuq)

Output:

```
[1] "B10243E" "B10243E" "B10243E" "B10243E"
```

To only replace the 8th character (here is a sample where I added `T` at the end of each item):

```
variables = c('B10247E1T', 'B10243E2T', 'B10243E3T', 'B10243E4T')
gsub('^(.{7}).', '\\1', variables)
```

Output of the [sample program](http://goo.gl/RChO0x) (not `ET` at the end of each item, the digit was removed):

```
[1] "B10247ET" "B10243ET" "B10243ET" "B10243ET"
```

Answer (score 4):

Try any of these.  The first removes the last character, the second replaces E and anything after it with E, the third returns the first 7 characters assuming there are 8 characters, the remaining each return the first 7 characters.  All are vectorized, i.e. `variables` may be a vector of character strings as in the question.

```
sub(".$", "", variables)

sub("E.*", "E", variables)

sub("^(.{7}).", "\\1", variables)

sub("^(.{7}).*", "\\1", variables)

substr(variables, 1, 7)

substring(variables, 1, 7)

trimws("abc333", "right", "\\d") # requires R 3.6 (currently r-devel)
```

Here is a visualization of the regular expression in the third solution:

```
^(.{7}).
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vAzJx8q9kpsYqNN8)

and there is a visualization of the regular expression in the fourth solution:

```
^(.{7}).*
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/d8OveGQgajFV9azX)

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to remove after `E` you can capture everything after it and replace by `E`

```
sub("E(.*)", 'E', variables)
## [1] "B10243E" "B10243E" "B10243E" "B10243E"
```

Alternatively, you can count 7 characters using positive look behind and remove everything after

```
sub("(?<=.{7})(.)", "", variables, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "B10243E" "B10243E" "B10243E" "B10243E"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringr)
str_sub("your String", 1, -2)
```

maybe slower than the other ones, but a lot easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `str_sub` from `stringr` package.

```
library(stringr)
variables = c('B10243E1', 'B10243E2', 'B10243E3', 'B10243E4')
variables = str_sub (variables, start = 1, end = -2)
```

Output:

```
> variables
[1] "B10243E" "B10243E" "B10243E" "B10243E"
```